# Error: Missing or insufficient permissions firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having troubles with creating users in my app, I get an error that says I don't have sufficient permissions even though I should have permission. My security rules are allowing users to be created so I don't really understand why I am getting this error. What's even more strange is that it works on my mates computer, he can create users (with the exact same userdetails). He is on a pc and I on a mac not sure if that matters?

The error I get is the following:
`[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error 7, FIRFirestoreErrorDomain, Missing or insufficient permissions.)`

Our security rules are:

````
service cloud.firestore {
        //match /databases/{database}/documents {


  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /Users/{userId} {
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /Users/{document=**} {
        allow create;
    }


    match /Recipes/{document=**} {
        allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow update, delete: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }

    match /Recipes/{document=**}/newRatings {
    allow create, update: if request.auth != null;
    }

  }

} ```

Our code for registering users is:

´´´ import 'package:cibus/pages/loginScreens/username_screen.dart';
import 'package:cibus/pages/loginScreens/verify_screen.dart';
import 'package:cibus/services/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cibus/services/login/auth.dart';
import 'package:cibus/services/constants.dart';
import 'package:cibus/pages/loginScreens/e-sign_in_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_user_stream/firebase_user_stream.dart';
import 'package:cibus/services/my_page_view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cibus/services/login/user.dart';
import 'package:cibus/services/database.dart';
import 'package:cibus/pages/loading_screen.dart';

const registerButtonColor = kTurquoise;
const formSizedBox = SizedBox(height: 20.0);
const EdgeInsets formPadding =
    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0);
const TextStyle textStyleErrorMessage =
    TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0);
const TextStyle textStyleRegisterButton = TextStyle(color: Colors.white);

OutlineInputBorder textInputBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
);

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  RegisterScreen({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool loading = false;
  bool isVerified = false;
  //final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  String name = '';
  String description = '';
  String _currentUsername;
  int age = 0;
  int dropdownValue = null;
  final TextEditingController _pass = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _confirmPass = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? LoadingScreen()
        : Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text('Sign up to Cibus', style: TextStyle(color: kCoral)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: kCoral),
                  label: Text('Sign in', style: TextStyle(color: kCoral)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //widget.toggleView();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return EmailSignIn();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: formPadding,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      formSizedBox,
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: textInputBorder,
                          border: textInputBorder,
                          labelText: 'Email',
                        ),
                        validator: (val) =>
                            val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => email = val);
                        },
                      ),
                      formSizedBox,
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: textInputBorder,
                          border: textInputBorder,
                          labelText: 'Password',
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                        controller: _pass,
                        validator: (String val) {
                          Pattern pattern =
                              r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
                          RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
                          print(val);
                          if (val.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter password';
                          } else if (val.length < 8) {
                            return 'Minimum 8 characters required';
                          } else if (!val.contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'))) {
                            return 'One upper case letter required.';
                          } else if (!val.contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'))) {
                            return 'One lower case letter required.';
                          } else if (!val.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
                            return 'One digit required.';
                          } else if (!val
                              .contains(RegExp(r'[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]'))) {
                            return 'One special character required.';
                          } /*

                          else {
                            if (!regex.hasMatch(val))
                              return 'Enter valid password: \n'
                                  'Password must contain at least one upper case letter. \n'
                                  'Password must contain at least one lower case letter. \n'
                                  'Password must contain at least one digit. \n'
                                  'Password must contain at least one special character.'; */
                          else
                            return null;
                          //}
                        },
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => password = val);
                        },
                      ),
                      formSizedBox,
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: textInputBorder,
                          border: textInputBorder,
                          labelText: ' Re-enter Password',
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                        controller: _confirmPass,
                        validator: (String val) {
                          if (val.isEmpty)
                            return 'Re-enter password field is empty';
                          if (val != _pass.text)
                            return 'passwords do not match';
                          return null;
                        },
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => password = val);
                        },
                      ),
                      formSizedBox,
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: textInputBorder,
                          border: textInputBorder,
                          labelText: 'Name',
                        ),
                        validator: (val) =>
                            val.isEmpty ? 'Enter your name' : null,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => name = val);
                        },
                      ),
                      formSizedBox,
                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: textInputBorder,
                          border: textInputBorder,
                          labelText: 'Description',
                        ),
                        minLines: 5,
                        maxLines: 10,
                        validator: (val) =>
                            val.isEmpty ? 'Enter your description' : null,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() => description = val);
                        },
                      ),
                      formSizedBox,
                      TextFormField(
                          maxLength: 20,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: textInputBorder,
                            border: textInputBorder,
                            labelText: 'Username',
                          ),
                          validator: (val) {
                            if (val.length < 3)
                              return 'Username must be more than 2 characters';
                            /*else if (checkUsername == false)
                          return 'Username is allready taken';*/
                            return null; 

                          },
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentUsername = val;
                              print(_currentUsername);
                            });
                          }),
                      formSizedBox,
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: kCoral,
                        child: Text('Register', style: textStyleRegisterButton),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            setState(() => loading = true);
                            bool isUsernameFree = await DatabaseService()
                                .isUsernameTaken(username: _currentUsername);
                            print(' checkUsername: $isUsernameFree');
                            if (!isUsernameFree) {
                              dynamic result =
                                  await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                                      email, password, name, description, age);
                              if (result == null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  error = 'Email is already registered';
                                  _verificationEmailDialog();
                                });
                              } else {
                                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) {
                                      return VerifyScreen();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                error = 'Username is already taken';
                              });
                              _usernameDialog();
                            }
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        error,
                        style: textStyleErrorMessage,
                      ),
                    ])),
              ),
            ));
  }

  Future<void> _usernameDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Username is already taken'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                    'Unfortunately it seems like your username is allready taken. Please try another one'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Aight bruh'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  loading = false;
                });
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pop(); //TODO: When popping try to keep text in forms
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _verificationEmailDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Email is already in use'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                    'Unfortunately it seems like the email is already in use. Please try another one'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Aight bruh'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  loading = false;
                });
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pop(); //TODO: When popping try to keep text in forms
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


and here is the registerWithEmailAndPassword function:

 Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password,
      String name, String description, int age) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      user.sendEmailVerification();
      user.isEmailVerified;
      print('Email verification sent?');

      //create a new document for the user with the uid
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
          .updateUserData(name: name, description: description, age: age);
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserPicture(
          pictureURL:
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/independent-project-7edde.appspot.com/o/blank_profile_picture.png?alt=media&token=49efb712-d543-40ca-8e33-8c0fdb029ea5');
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
````

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that's generating the error.  Security rules by themselves are meaningless unless paired with client code that they are intended to allow or reject.

Comment: The allow create; or allow create: if true; gives the same error unfortunately.

I have now edited the question to include our register code which gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake on my part with the Security rules. I had that users could create users but they could only read if they were authenticated, so when I checked if username was taken the error occurred since I did not have the read permissions. I just added the read part on users and it works

```
match /Users/{document=**} {
        allow create: if true;
      allow read: if true;
    } 
´´´
```